# vue2 component: force update computed propriety using methods

Tags: vuejs2, splice, computed-properties

i'm trying to update a computed propriety using a method inside a component,
here the example:

```
props: ['selezionati'],
computed:{
    listaSelezionati() {
        return this.selezionati
    }
},
methods:{
    rimuoviSotto : function(index,indexparent){
        var obj = JSON.stringify(this.listaSelezionati[0][indexparent].sottoservizio[index]);
        alert(obj);
        var mod = this.listaSelezionati[0][indexparent].sottoservizio.splice(index,1);
        vue.set(this.listaSelezionati,mod);
    }
}
```

basically i want to splice a sub array nested data,

the obj var is only to debug, and trigger the correct value, i have tried to apply the array splice without var, it seems to work, but don't apply the modify to component view, so i was trying to use the vue.set but the console return me "is not a function".

basically what can i do to update the computed propriety to the view?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

computed properties are dependent properties . They update when their dependent `data` properties which are reactive update.

So assign the vaue of the prop to a data property

```
props: ['selezionati'],
data((){
    return{
        listaSelezionati: this.selezionati
    }
},
methods:{
    rimuoviSotto : function(index,indexparent){
        var obj = JSON.stringify(this.listaSelezionati[0][indexparent].sottoservizio[index]);
        alert(obj);
        var mod = this.listaSelezionati[0][indexparent].sottoservizio.splice(index,1);
        this.listaSelezionati = mod;
    }
}
```

If you want to update the prop that you are reviving from the parent , then you should use [events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events) as [props are one-way data flow](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#One-Way-Data-Flow)

Comment: i have tried with data, but this do problems on template (propiety not defined), but i will try wth emit on props

Comment: @PdsInk can you show hoe you tried with data... events are only if you want the data in the parent that you are passing as prop needs to b changed

Comment: @Vasni Krisna basically i comment the computed propriety and add  the props to the data

 data: function(){
  return{listaSelezionati: this.selezionati

Comment: @PdsInk the why do you get property not defined

Comment: because in the template i have some references to the props propriety that won't be read if i use the data method... for example 

<template v-if="selezionato[0].lineaApparte == 'gialla'">

give me problems... (selezionato is generated using a v-for)

Comment: @Vasni Krisna, i must say that i have already a method that update the computed propriety and the view without problem:

  rimuovi : function(index){
   this.listaSelezionati.splice(index,1)
  },

but when i go deeply to the array (like the original topic) it don't work

Answer (score 0):

i solved using  $forceUpdate();
basically in the method i must force the computed propriety